# php_imap.dll for php v 5.2.6 apache for windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, php-extension

I am having problems installing the php_imap.dll extension for a webserver running apache and php  5.2.6 on windows server 2003 r2.

I have other extensions installed so I know the basics. I have confirmed that my php.ini file is pointing the the right extension directory. This is in my php.ini config

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
```

and I put the php_imap.dll in the /ext folder of apache where the others are located.

Then in the php error log I get:

```
12-Jan-2012 10:09:48] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_imap.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I think the issue is I have the wrong version of the php_imap.dll. The version I have is from my windows workstation that is running wamp against php version 5.3. and this works. But when I copy that same .dll to the server runnning a different version of php it does not work. Does anyone know where I can find the correct version of the php_imap.dll?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

At the above site they say I should download the correct version, and some dlls are listed, but not the one that I need.

```
PHP API 20041225
Thread Safety   enabled
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--with-gd=shared" "--with-extra-includes=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDK\Include;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\ATL\INCLUDE;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\INCLUDE;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\MFC\INCLUDE" "--with-extra-libs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDK\Lib;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\LIB;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\MFC\LIB"
```

Comment: There are 3 possible problems so please post : 1) API version, 2) thread safety 3) VC9/VC6 compilation version

Comment: Added more info to original post that may help. Looks like VC9.

Comment: All this scrap will be solved in once if you use ZendServer CE with PHP 5.2 stack.It's free.It's just apache2.2 with PHP and some optimalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need this `php_imap.dll` for php5.2.6, you will find it in [WampServer addons archive](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/PHP/). There is a [5.2.6 addon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/PHP/WampServer2-PHP526.exe/download)

It will not replace your php/apache current installation, but this addon contain a lot of non standard extensions for PHP

My advice is to extract it on your workstation, and take only the `php_imap.dll` and drop it in you `ext/` folder in windows server 2003 r2.

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is also my suggestion.Great.