# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_imap.dll

Tags: php, codeigniter

I built an application using codeigniter 3 and it worked fine on my local host

but when i uploaded it to my godaddy server i get the below error. Because of this error none of my javascript files are working. I did some research and found out that its some extension related to mail... But i dont use that all..

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_imap.dll' - ./php_imap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

Can someone tell me how can i get rid of that error? I cant install that extension on godaddy so i need to find another way

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838563/php-imap-dll-for-php-v-5-2-6-apache-for-windows

Comment: Is codeigniter itself causing the error or is it the app that you created causing the error?  Search for `imap` in the files your uploading to godaddy and update your question with the results of the search.